# How to use TestFX to test a scene's contents using JavaFXML

Tags: java, javafx, testfx

I'm wondering how I'm supposed to be testing contents of certain scenes in JavaFXML when using TestFX. 
Examples include these links:
https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/blob/master/subprojects/testfx-junit5/src/test/java/org/testfx/framework/junit5/ApplicationRuleTest.java

https://medium.com/@mglover/java-fx-testing-with-testfx-c3858b571320

The first link constructs the scene within the test class, and the latter uses a pre-defined scene stored in its own class.
How am I supposed to do something similar to this when using JavaFXML instead of JavaFX where the scenes' structures are defined in an fxml file instead of java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is giving your components fx:id-s in your fxml files, and then something like:

```
public class ChangeProfilesMenuControllerTest extends ApplicationTest {
    Pane mainroot;
    Stage mainstage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
      mainroot = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("ChangeProfilesMenU.fxml"));
      mainstage = stage;
      stage.setScene(new Scene(mainroot));
      stage.show();
      stage.toFront();

   }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{

    }

   @After
   public void tearDown () throws Exception {
     FxToolkit.hideStage();
     release(new KeyCode[]{});
     release(new MouseButton[]{});
   }

   @Test
   public void addingAndDeletingProfiles() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      ListView<String> listview = (ListView<String>) mainroot.lookup("#listview");
      clickOn("#textfield");
      write("This is a test");
      clickOn("#createnewprofile");
      ...
  }
```

If you want to acces your controller class instance:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        this.mainstage = stage;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GameOn2.fxml"));
        this.mainroot = loader.load();
        this.controller = loader.getController();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainroot));
        stage.show();
        stage.toFront();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the correct way for me to go. However, I'm receiving an error of:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.`
on a line containing `mainRoot = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("primary.fxml"));`

Comment: @ancd3ea4 check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other